# If DateTime Object Is Null

Tags: php, sql, sql-server

I am returning some search results after form submit. All is working fine, until I get to a field that is SMALLDATETIME and allows NULL. At least one of the returned rows has the field as NULL. As you can see in the code below, when it is not NULL I am converting it from Date to String no problem, but i get an error Message for the rows with NULL.

Any ideas?

Code:

```
$search_results = sqlsrv_query($database_connection, $search_results_sql, array(), array( "Scrollable" => SQLSRV_CURSOR_KEYSET ));

if($search_results){
    $returned_rows = sqlsrv_has_rows($search_results);
    if($returned_rows === true){
        getAssetSearchData($search_results);
    }
}
function getAssetSearchData($search_results){

while($search_results_option = sqlsrv_fetch_object($search_results)){
    echo "
<tr>
        <td class='col45'>".date_format($search_results_option->HardwareAssetLastUpdateTime,"d/m/Y H:i")."</td>
        <td class='col46'>".$search_results_option->HardwareAssetLastUpdatedByName."</td>
        <td class='col47'>".date_format($search_results_option->HardwareAssetLastDiscoveryScanDate,"d/m/Y H:i")."</td></tr>";
    }
}
```

Error Message:

> Warning: date_format() expects parameter 1 to be DateTimeInterface,
>   null given in

Comment: you could add a check if($search_results_option->HardwareAssetLastUpdateTime === NULL). Maybe it could help you when you add  the "on update current_timestamp" Flag to the LastUpdateTime in your DB

Comment: date_format doesn't work with null date values. You should have to manage this case

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<td>".(
   is_null($search_results_option->HardwareAssetLastDiscoveryScanDate) ? '' : 
       date_format($search_results_option->HardwareAssetLastDiscoveryScanDate,
        "d/m/Y H:i")
    )
 ."</td>";
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
<td class='col45'>".date_format(new DateTime( $search_results_option->HardwareAssetLastUpdateTime ),"d/m/Y H:i")."</td>
<td class='col46'>".$search_results_option->HardwareAssetLastUpdatedByName."</td>
<td class='col47'>".date_format(new DateTime( $search_results_option->HardwareAssetLastDiscoveryScanDate ),"d/m/Y H:i")."</td></tr>";
```

`date_format()` need the date to be in DateTime format when supplied, you are passing a string.

The other thing may be that `$search_results_option` is empty

For NULL values:

( $search_results_option->HardwareAssetLastDiscoveryScanDate != null ? date_format(new DateTime( $search_results_option->HardwareAssetLastDiscoveryScanDate ),"d/m/Y H:i") : '' )

This will check for a null value, if it is not null it will display the formatted datetime, els eit will display nothing

Comment: $search_results_option is empty for HardwareAssetLastDiscoveryScanDate